# Django rest framework creating new record with serializer when foreign key doesn't exist

Tags: django-rest-framework

Say that I have these two models:

```
class App(models.Model):
 label = models.CharField(max_length=32)

class Endpoint(models.Model):
 main_app = models.ForeignKeyField(App, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 ...

class EndpointSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
 main_app = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=App.objects.all(), slug_field='label')

  class Meta:
   model = ReviewComponent
   fields = [
    'id', 
    'main_app'
        ]
```

When I want to create a new Endpoint with an existing App, it's quite trivial:

```
serializer = EndpointSerializer(data={'main_app': 'foo'...})
serializer.is_valid()
serializer.save()
```

but when I want to create a new endpoint with an app that doesn't exist, this approach doesn't work, what's the correct way to do this?

I could always add a serializer for App, create the App through the AppSerializer and then resume creation on EndpointSerializer but I can't believe this to be the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example of this in the Django rest framework docs here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers

Using a serializer for the App model seems a fairly common way to manage creation of the App object in Django rest framework. Adapting this to the models in your question could look something like this:

```
from django.db import models
from rest_framework import serializers


class App(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=32)


class Endpoint(models.Model):
    main_app = models.ForeignKey(App, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class AppSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = App
        fields = '__all__'


class EndpointSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    main_app = AppSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Endpoint
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        main_app_data = validated_data.pop('main_app')
        main_app = App.objects.get_or_create(**main_app_data)
        validated_data['main_app'] = main_app
        return super().create(validated_data)
----------------------------------------------------
>>> from qqq.models import App, Endpoint, AppSerializer, EndpointSerializer
>>> serializer = EndpointSerializer(data={'main_app': {'label': 'label-1'}})   # notice the nested dict here
>>> serializer.is_valid()
True
>>> serializer.save()
<Endpoint: Endpoint object (1)>
>>> App.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<App: App object (1)>]>
>>> Endpoint.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Endpoint: Endpoint object (1)>]>
```

You mentioned you don't want to have to create an `AppSerializer`, however without it you run into two issues that I can think of.

1. When creating the Endpoint and App instances in the line `EndpointSerializer(data={'main_app'...` django rest will always try and lookup the App object in the App table and never find it, thus throwing an error.
2. All of Django Rest's `<Thing>RelatedField`'s are read only by default. So in order to write the nested data you need to do it manually by overriding the `.create()` and/or `.update()` methods.
   [image]